# How to upload extension on magento connect?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.6

I have created a extension and want to upload on magento connect but when I upload it on magento connect it gives me following error:-

```
Unable to save version. Filename is not valid. Expected filename without ext...
```

I checked my extension which is working great on all versions.

Please help me to sort out this error.

Comment: follow the instructions given in the extension development guide by magebto

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

1. Log in to Magento Admin panel
2. From the Admin panel, select System > Magento Connect > Package Extensions.
3. On Package Info section, add extension name in Name field, for example my_stackoverflow
4. Fill all other fields, use this guide: http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf

When extension will be packed, go to /path/to/magento/var/connect/ folder and you'll see my_stackoverflow-1.0.0.tgz file. This file should be upload on Magento connect site.

Comment: yes I already created that extension but when I upload this extension on magento connect above error shows.

Comment: Main tricks: Channel field on Package Info tab should be allways 'community'. On Authors tab user field must match the user field of your magentocommerce.com account (I also do it for email field), Name field is your admin login on admin area ('admin' by default).

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.Actually package name should be same as your extension key name.In my case extension key at magento connect was "test_data" and package name in package.xml file was "Test_Data". I just change the package name and extension uploaded successfully.